# Convert or Cast VARCHAR to INT; Update column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, sql-update

**Disclaimer:** 
I am still learning SQL so I apologize if my question comes off as amateur-ish or is otherwise a very simple answer. I have no formal training. I am teaching myself.

The title may be a bit confusing, as I'm not entirely sure how to word this for a title.

Basically, I want to convert a column in a table thats currently `VARCHAR` into an `INT`. The column contains only numbers formatted as such:

```
00001
00005
02150
```

These are essentially *ID's* which will be appended to a `Name column` later for other purposes. If its necessary to do so, I'd also like to know how to convert the end result `INT` to `VARCHAR` for the append portion.

Here's what I have right now:

> SELECT CONVERT(INT, LocNo)

It returns the results I expect but I think I need to somehow update the existing `LocNo column` or otherwise put it in a new column for forward use.

What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: You know you will lose the leading zeros right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE TableName
SET LocNo =  CONVERT(INT, LocNo)
```

If you want new column, add new column to table and then do update

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD NewCol Int Null

UPDATE TableName
SET NewCol =  CONVERT(INT, LocNo)
```

When Selecting and appending to varchar you can do

```
SELECT CAST(LocNO As VARCHAR) + Name as NameAppended From TableName
```

If you want `0's` back in `LocNo/newCol` then

```
 SELECT right('00000' + CAST(LocNO As VARCHAR),0) + Name as NameAppended 
 From TableName
```

Comment: Zero padding `LocNo` to a constant width is probably something the OP would appreciate when appending.

Comment: I appreciate the info and this works perfectly for me. I don't need the 0's back but I'll keep that info in mind for future use.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET LocNo =  CONVERT(INT, LocNo)
```